# MySql query to pull 2different data from a single column and display them separetely in 2 column

Tags: mysql

```
                   name         value   

        FirstName   Anand
        LastName    kumar
```

table name:uservar

i have the database table like this.. give me the mysql query to display the table like below i am giving.

```
                 FirstName          LastName

                   Anand             Kumar
```

Please help me out.